Where is rails-sprockets asset_path?
This may be a long shot... I'm trying to track down some unexpected behavior in a Rails 6.1 application. The details are not important here, but issue has led me to the AssetUrlProcessor class in Sprockets::Rails - https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/tree/master/lib/sprockets/rails.
The Processor's call method invokes asset_path on what I believe is a dynamically defined subclass of Sprockets::Context. I'm interested in seeing exactly what that method does, but I'm having trouble figuring out exactly where the method is defined for that context. There are a couple of methods with that name defined in Sprockets::Rails::Helper, but I've tried instrumenting them with console output and neither seem to be what is being called.
Is anyone familiar with this code who might be able to help me identify the relevant method definition?

context.method(:asset_path) #=> #<Method: #<Class:0x00007ff45e15dcb8>(ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper)#asset_path(source, options=...) /home/alex/.rbenv/versions/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/actionview-7.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb:187>
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.2.1/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb#L187

Ah, perfect! Thank you so much!
